# Updating a column with a Count of data from another column in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

As the title suggests, trying to take the count or possibly distinct count of a column, we call it year, to count the number of a years for an individual or populated ID and place it another column in the same table. Here is an idea of what I have so far and we want to update the table. Thank you.

[image: Here is what we have so far]

Comment: please instead of screenshot paste the code here

Answer (score 2):

Join group table to updated table directly:

```
UPDATE outputtable O JOIN 
  (SELECT personID, COUNT(DISTINCT year) AS countYear
   FROM outputtable GROUP BY personID) temp ON O.personID=temp.personID
SET O.N=temp.countYear
```